# Python: Define a function that takes a list of many points

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameters, computer-science

When I write my function like this, it works perfectly:

```
a = [(9,0), (6,6), (1,15), (243, 635), (9, 7), (7,8), (2,4)]
def func(a)
   #function calculation
return Min dist
```

But this function is not very feasible since it will only calculate the given ‘a’ within the code. Is there a way to make the function recognize ‘a’ as a list containing however many points the user inputs? For example, I want the function to work like this:

```
def func(a)
   #calculation
return Min dist
```

In console:

```
[In:] a = [(9,0), (6,6), (1,15), (243, 635), (9, 7), (7,8), (2,4)]
[O:] 3.436788
```

Comment: Just call `func(a)`. That fact that you named the parameter the same thing as the list is irrelevant. You can pass any list to `f`. It doesn't matter what you called it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you already can:

#### your module

```
def func(a)
    #function calculation
    return Min dist
```

#### your main

```
a = [(9,0), (6,6), (1,15), (243, 635), (9, 7), (7,8), (2,4)]
b = [(9,0), (6,6), (1,15), (243, 635), (9, 7), (7,8), (2,4)]
c = [(9,0), (6,6), (1,15), (243, 635), (9, 7), (7,8), (2,4)]
func(a)
func(b)
func(c)
```